# React Highcharts Sunburst Not Rendering with API Data

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm working on a React project using Highcharts to render a Sunburst chart. The chart is supposed to visualize data fetched from an API, but it's not rendering, and there are no errors in the console. I suspect the issue might be with the way I'm transforming the data for Highcharts.

Here's the component code:

```
import React from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import sunburst from "highcharts/modules/sunburst";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

function extractData(data) {
  const ids = [];
  const labels = [];
  const parents = [];
  const values = [];

  function traverse(element, parentId) {
    if (element.children) {
      element.children.f`your text`orEach((child) => {
        if (child.Código && child["Sub-Setor"]) {
          ids.push(child.Código);
          labels.push(child["Sub-Setor"]);
          parents.push(parentId);
          values.push(child["Part. (%)"]);
        }
        if (child.children) {
          traverse(child, child.name);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  data.forEach((sector) => {
    if (sector.children) {
      sector.children.forEach((subSector) => {
        traverse(subSector, sector.name);
      });
    }
  });

  return { ids, labels, parents, values };
}

function fetchData() {
  return fetch("http://rar.xxx.xxx/api/indices/data/IBOV").then((res) =>
    res.json()
  );
}

// Inicializa o módulo Sunburst
sunburst(Highcharts);

function SunburstChart({ data }) {
  const { data: indices, isLoading, error } = useQuery(["sunburst"], fetchData);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Carregando...</p>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <p>Ocorreu um erro: {error.message}</p>;
  }

  const extratedData = extractData(indices);
  console.log(extratedData);

  // Configura as opções do gráfico
  const options = {
    series: [
      {
        type: "sunburst",
        data: extratedData,
        allowDrillToNode: true,
        cursor: "pointer",
        dataLabels: {
          format: "{point.name}",
        },
      },
    ],
    title: {
      text: "Meu Gráfico Sunburst",
    },
  };

  return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />;
}

export default SunburstChart;
```

The extractData function is supposed to reshape the API data into a format suitable for Highcharts, but the chart remains blank. The transformed data looks like this:

Object

ids: ["EMBR3", "AZUL4", "CCRO3", "GOLL4", "RAIL3", "BRFS3", "JBSS3", "MRFG3", "BEEF3", "SMTO3", …] (85)

labels: ["Mat Transporte", "Transporte", "Transporte", "Transporte", "Transporte", "Alimentos Processados", "Alimentos Processados", "Alimentos Processados", "Alimentos Processados", "Alimentos Processados", …] (85)

parents: ["Bens Indls", "Bens Indls", "Bens Indls", "Bens Indls", "Bens Indls", "Consumo Não-Cíclico", "Consumo Não-Cíclico", "Consumo Não-Cíclico", "Consumo Não-Cíclico", "Consumo Não-Cíclico", …] (85)

values: [0.667, 0.261, 0.591, 0.082, 1.305, 1.092, 1.127, 0.11, 0.084, 0.224, …] (85)

I'm expecting a Sunburst chart visualizing the sectors, sub-sectors and tickers and their corresponding values, but the chart container stays empty without any error messages. Can someone help me identify what's wrong with the extractData function or how the data is being passed to Highcharts?

...........................................................

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt your data to the structure required by Highcharts, so an array of objects, not an object with arrays.

Below you can find an example of how you can convert your existing structure.

```
const extratedData = {
  ids: ["EMBR3", "AZUL4", "CCRO3", "GOLL4", "RAIL3", "BRFS3", "JBSS3", "MRFG3", "BEEF3", "SMTO3"],
  labels: ["Mat Transporte", "Transporte", "Transporte", "Transporte", "Transporte", "Alimentos Processados", "Alimentos Processados", "Alimentos Processados", "Alimentos Processados", "Alimentos Processados"],
  parents: ["Bens Indls", "Bens Indls", "Bens Indls", "Bens Indls", "Bens Indls", "Consumo Não-Cíclico", "Consumo Não-Cíclico", "Consumo Não-Cíclico", "Consumo Não-Cíclico", "Consumo Não-Cíclico"],
  values: [0.667, 0.261, 0.591, 0.082, 1.305, 1.092, 1.127, 0.11, 0.084, 0.224]
};

const processedData = extratedData.ids.map((id, index) => ({
  id,
  name: extratedData.labels[index],
  parent: extratedData.parents[index],
  value: extratedData.values[index]
}));

[...new Set(extratedData.parents)].forEach(parent => {
  processedData.push({
    id: parent,
    name: parent
  });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/om61vsk3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.data

Comment: I did something similar but in the backend, it worked pretty well. Thanks a lot!